# Security deposit Interest return

Tags: interest-rate, rental-property

I'm getting ready to receive my $1,900 security deposit back on an apartment and I'm trying to figure out what is the additional interest I should receive at the time the account was set up the escrow interest rate was .20%

Comment: Location will be needed to determine if there will be any interest required. Country is needed for sure, and in the US the law varies by state.

Answer (score 4):

Multiply $1900 by 0.002 and then by the number of years that the security deposit was held. If you get more than that, count yourself as lucky.